# String formatting according to number of decimal points

Tags: string, scala, digits

I want to write a string of variable values in a formatted way, according to the following:

Maximum decimal points is 3.
If there are less than 3 significant points than less are written.

For example:
the number 1.53848 will be written as 1.538
the number 1.0 will be written as 1 (rather than 1.000).

```
val variable1 = 1.
val variable2 = 1.53848
language = "%s average value is %.3f and %.3f".format(variable1, variable2)
```

Comment: Rounding isn't an issue. I don't mind if the number will be rounded or not. but i want 1.5 to result in 1, 1. to result in 1, 1.204964 to result in 1.204 or 1.205

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
def format(d: Double) =
    BigDecimal(d).scale match {
        case x if x > 2 => "%.3f".format(d)
        case _ => d.toInt.toString
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just removing the zeroes (and possibly the comma/separator character)?

```
def formatted(d: Double) = "%.3f".format(d).replaceAll(",?0+$", "")
```

Comment: This works great except for the following situation: when entering the variable1 = 1.0 i get the result 1. (i don't want the period, i want to get 1)

Comment: Sorry, swedish locale, you would have to replace the comma in the regex (which separates fractions in sweden) with \\. so that the period is removed.

Comment: I wrote:   def formatted(d: Double) = "%.3f".format(d).replaceAll(".?0+$", ""). I get the following (unwanted results): variable1 = 1.2 is formatted to 1., variable2 = 2.302684 is formatted to 2.303, variable3 = 1.

Comment: period needs to be escaped as it means "match any character" in regex, so that means "\." and since backslash is also the escape character in Java/Scala strings you have to escape it twice, so it needs to be "\\."